# SSH is refusing me (all of a sudden)

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, ssh

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server which has automatic security updates enabled. SSH is configured with the following options

```
Port 22
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Of course i have setup an SSH key in my .ssh folder of the user. I have setup 10 servers like this, but all of a sudden one server is refusing me.

```
$ ssh -vv root@149.56.*.*
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/tpg/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/tpg/.ssh/config line 84: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 149.56.*.* [149.56.*.*] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 149.56.*.* port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 149.56.*.* port 22: Connection refused
```

I have no console (kvm) only a rescue boot which i can mount the filesystem and edit files. So i edited the sshd_config file to accept root and password, but it still refusing me.

In rescue mode i cannot repair packages on the filesystem (as far as i know) so i don't know how to get this server start accepting me again. I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

As far as i know i do not have ufw installed (/lib/ufw is not there).

edit: did a nmap to the server and it appears there is no port 22 open. Anyone know how i can start the sshd server without access?

---

Excerpt of results from `grep -rn sshd /var/log`

```
./auth.log:18607:Mar  9 12:58:58 komodoNA sshd[26971]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18616:Mar  9 13:02:10 komodoNA sshd[27172]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18619:Mar  9 13:03:08 komodoNA sshd[27224]: fatal: no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1 server hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160 [preauth]
./auth.log:18620:Mar  9 13:03:08 komodoNA sshd[27225]: fatal: no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1 server hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160 [preauth]
./auth.log:18621:Mar  9 13:03:11 komodoNA sshd[27228]: fatal: no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1 server hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160 [preauth]
./auth.log:18624:Mar  9 13:04:05 komodoNA sshd[27279]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18629:Mar  9 13:06:08 komodoNA sshd[27381]: Invalid user user from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18630:Mar  9 13:06:08 komodoNA sshd[27381]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
./auth.log:18631:Mar  9 13:06:08 komodoNA sshd[27381]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18638:Mar  9 13:09:25 komodoNA sshd[27533]: Invalid user user1 from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18639:Mar  9 13:09:25 komodoNA sshd[27533]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user1 [preauth]
./auth.log:18640:Mar  9 13:09:25 komodoNA sshd[27533]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18645:Mar  9 13:11:24 komodoNA sshd[27636]: Invalid user user01 from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18646:Mar  9 13:11:24 komodoNA sshd[27636]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user01 [preauth]
./auth.log:18647:Mar  9 13:11:24 komodoNA sshd[27636]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18652:Mar  9 13:13:20 komodoNA sshd[27740]: Invalid user user2 from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18653:Mar  9 13:13:20 komodoNA sshd[27740]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user2 [preauth]
./auth.log:18654:Mar  9 13:13:20 komodoNA sshd[27740]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18659:Mar  9 13:15:16 komodoNA sshd[27843]: Invalid user user3 from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18660:Mar  9 13:15:16 komodoNA sshd[27843]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user3 [preauth]
./auth.log:18661:Mar  9 13:15:16 komodoNA sshd[27843]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18664:Mar  9 13:16:43 komodoNA sshd[27897]: Received disconnect from 59.49.224.224: 11: ok [preauth]
./auth.log:18669:Mar  9 13:17:10 komodoNA sshd[27959]: Invalid user user02 from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18670:Mar  9 13:17:10 komodoNA sshd[27959]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user02 [preauth]
./auth.log:18671:Mar  9 13:17:11 komodoNA sshd[27959]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18676:Mar  9 13:19:06 komodoNA sshd[28062]: Invalid user user03 from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18677:Mar  9 13:19:06 komodoNA sshd[28062]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user03 [preauth]
./auth.log:18678:Mar  9 13:19:06 komodoNA sshd[28062]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18683:Mar  9 13:21:01 komodoNA sshd[28119]: Invalid user user1 from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18684:Mar  9 13:21:01 komodoNA sshd[28119]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user1 [preauth]
./auth.log:18685:Mar  9 13:21:01 komodoNA sshd[28119]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18688:Mar  9 13:22:57 komodoNA sshd[28222]: Invalid user user2 from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18689:Mar  9 13:22:57 komodoNA sshd[28222]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user2 [preauth]
./auth.log:18690:Mar  9 13:22:57 komodoNA sshd[28222]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18695:Mar  9 13:24:54 komodoNA sshd[28326]: Invalid user user3 from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18696:Mar  9 13:24:54 komodoNA sshd[28326]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user3 [preauth]
./auth.log:18697:Mar  9 13:24:54 komodoNA sshd[28326]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18702:Mar  9 13:26:49 komodoNA sshd[28429]: Invalid user usertest from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18703:Mar  9 13:26:49 komodoNA sshd[28429]: input_userauth_request: invalid user usertest [preauth]
./auth.log:18704:Mar  9 13:26:50 komodoNA sshd[28429]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18709:Mar  9 13:28:47 komodoNA sshd[28532]: Invalid user dev from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18710:Mar  9 13:28:47 komodoNA sshd[28532]: input_userauth_request: invalid user dev [preauth]
./auth.log:18711:Mar  9 13:28:47 komodoNA sshd[28532]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18714:Mar  9 13:29:55 komodoNA sshd[28586]: fatal: no matching cipher found: client aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc server aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr [preauth]
./auth.log:18715:Mar  9 13:29:58 komodoNA sshd[28588]: fatal: no matching cipher found: client aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc server aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr [preauth]
./auth.log:18718:Mar  9 13:30:01 komodoNA sshd[28590]: Did not receive identification string from 123.31.32.58
./auth.log:18719:Mar  9 13:30:55 komodoNA sshd[28640]: Invalid user mysql from 181.39.89.146
./auth.log:18720:Mar  9 13:30:55 komodoNA sshd[28640]: input_userauth_request: invalid user mysql [preauth]
./auth.log:18721:Mar  9 13:30:55 komodoNA sshd[28640]: Connection closed by 181.39.89.146 [preauth]
./auth.log:18726:Mar  9 13:32:59 komodoNA sshd[28744]: fatal: no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1 server hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160 [preauth]
./auth.log:18729:Mar  9 13:33:02 komodoNA sshd[28795]: fatal: no matching mac found: client hmac-md5,hmac-sha1 server hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160 [preauth]
```

---

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` content:

```
root@rescue:/mnt/root# cat /mnt/etc/ssh/sshd_config | egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*#|^[[:space:]]*$|^[[:space:]]*;'
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

Comment: Is it only via SSH? Only on port 22?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your edit. Assuming SSH is down,

You can, from your rescue mode, check the logs and see why SSH is not coming up.

- Go the the rescue mode
- Log into the server
- `cd` into `/var/log`
- run something like `grep -rn sshd .`

This should start bringing results relating to the SSH server. See if you can start finding errors and start posting those back. If there is a timestamp, see if you can find errors since the last time you restarted the server.

Check disk space and that your user is not in any disallow stanza.

```
DenyUsers <username>
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RWGiepF9 those are mostly the errors, but all log lines are to much too paste. It looks like i am being hammered and that is crashed my ssh daemon. But i can't find the log file where it reports the error why it is not starting my ssh daemon :(

Comment: SSH seems to be running. If not, it wouldn't see those request you tried. Can you upload your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? It's seems to be configuration, but not sure where.

Comment: Saw your updated comment. Is 181.39.*.* _not_ your IP?

Comment: No that is not my IP. But could be the nmap scanner

Comment: > [+] Nmap scan report for ns*ip-149-56-29.net (149.56.*.*)<br>
Host is up (0.081s latency).<br>
Not shown: 99 closed ports<br>
<br>
PORT    STATE    SERVICE<br>
445/tcp filtered microsoft-ds<br>

Comment: Here is my sshd_config http://pastebin.com/BV95rCMC

Comment: Those are logging attempts, not nmap. `user`, `user1`, `user01` are the usernames tried.  The last two lines on the sshd_config seem to be additional. Could you add more verbosity to your SSH command and to the ssh server by changing, `LogLevel INFO` to `LogLevel DEBUG`?

Comment: I have set LogLevel DEBUG, but it isn't starting the sshd server at all. Also set some commands in rc.local to check status of sshd and send the output into a logfile but it isn't doing anything. Nmap shows me port 22 is closed. Time on server now is 18.33 and last time sshd reported something in auth.log is 13.57 before i did the reboot and found out it was broke. So sshd was working when i rebooted, but it isn't coming up anymore and i don't know how to start it without shell access

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55097/discussion-between-rovr138-and-alex).